# When I use the asterisk to indicate the field width, how come it is missing one space?

Tags: c, printf, placeholder, turbo-c

```
printf("12345678\n");
printf("%*c%*c, 2, 'a', 2, 'b');
```

On the console, I was expecting that `a` would be below `3` and `b` below `6` since the way I understand it is that I indicated two spaces before each character. However, the output shows that `a` is below `2` and, `b` is below `4`.

Comment: use this printf(" %*c %*c", 2, 'a', 2, 'b');  you should give some space in begining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that, is that the number in front of a format specifier defines the field width not a margin or a padding. In the format `%ns`, where `n` is an integer number and `s` is your specifier of choice, `n` defines that you are reserving n spaces for what ever you will replace the specifier with. That said, if the information which replaces the specifier will need more than n spaces, it will take the spaces it needs.

So if you want the letters `a` and `b` to appear below `3` and `6` you need to reserve three spaces for each letter not two.

```
printf("%*c%*c, 3, 'a', 3, 'b');
```